# Veracrypt to Veracrypt copy hangs

Tags: windows-10, backup, external-hard-drive, veracrypt

For several years I've made a backup of my backup by plugging both USB external HDDs into my Windows 10 laptop, mounting them via Veracrypt and then simply dragging and dropping with File Explorer. The backups are huge, involving many files, so the transfers sometimes took many hours, but it worked.

As of a few months ago, however, this operation has hung very quickly. After a dozen files File Explorer will lock up and I'd have to resort to the Task Manager to kill it. On a few occasions I got a heart attack because I was no longer able to mount the 'main' backup and had to run `chkdsk m: /f` to fix errors. (I'm relatively confident that the HDD is fine and that something just got messed up while File Explorer was hanging.)

Thinking that perhaps File Explorer was to blame, I tried robocopy. Same thing. It hung after less than 10 files. I didn't have to go to Task Manager to kill it, but it took a minute after I tried to close the window. I later checked the file where it appeared to choke and it's fine.

Perplexed, I decided to copy a big folder (50+ GB across 480+ files) from the 'main' back to my laptop. It worked no problem. Then I copied these files to the 'backup' backup. That worked, too.

So it would seem that I only have this hanging issue (which for years never happened) when I copy from one external Veracrypt HDD to another external Veracrypt HDD. This is bizarre. Any ideas? Thank  you.

Comment: Instead of copying the files, why not bitcopy the veracrypt volume?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's now seeming clear that the 'main' backup is dead. I decided to run a `chkdsk /f` and it's been running for over 12 hours finding `Corruption was found while examining files in directory \` and then a number if parenthesis. I can't believe that it would die like that, but it's not looking good.

Comment: You shoukd abort the chkfsk and attempt a bitcopy of the disk using ddrescue. Then do chkdsk on that.

Comment: @davidgo, that might take some time, but I'll give it a go and post back here eventually. Thank you.

Comment: I spoke with someone in tech support for the drive I bought who suggested plugged the drive into a Mac and running `sudo fsck_exfat -d diskXsX`, which apparently is much faster than `chkdsk`. I might give that a try before ddrescue.

Comment: if you value your data do a ddrescue first. Your drive is likely stuffed and everything you do significantly increases the risk of data loss.

Comment: Thank you, @davidgo. It's a 6TB HDD that was between 1/2 and 2/3 full when it started acting up. I was just able to mount it with Veracrypt but when I try to open the drive I get the "format disk" pop-up and then the "unrecognized file system" when I cancel that. I'll try the ddrescue.

By the way, the support guy said that he's confident this is a software issue, the hardware is fine and that after I reformat I should be good to go. What do you think of that?

Comment: I do not wish to contradict someone who has seen the actual hardware, Your description of a "hanging issue" and 12 hours for a chkdsk are a concern (although I confess I am a Linux person so don't not expert in chkdsk).  I have seen many hard drives which are dying where chkdsks take forever to complete because they can't read the data efficiently.  Did the expert query the SMART info on the drive?  Very often that will give insights into the drive health.

Comment: @davidgo I decided to give it a go and downloaded ddrescue, but 7zip won't open it because it's a .lz. I found another application to unzip .lz files, but before installing that I tried to find any tutorial on running ddrescue on a Windows machine to recover files from an external HDD. Every page has different information and recommends different software. I've very surprised at how complicated this is. I tried mounting it on a Mac, but Veracrypt wasn't accepting the Admin password. Thanks but it looks like I'll need to pay someone to help me.